# Word 2010, how to update protected document

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word-2010

The document has one "Section Break" with e.g. "Text Form Fields" above. To make this Form Field work properly I use "Restrict Editing", allow "Filling in Forms", "Select Sections" and then protect Section 1. Then "Start Enforcing Protection".
Now when the document is protected above the Section Break you can't use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>and <kbd>F9</kbd> to make an update of the fields, etc. of the document below the Section Break. 
Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: The logical solution would be to "unlock" or "disable protection" update the contents of the document, then enable protection again, thus solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks, but this is a template and I don't want the users to disable the protection.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the expected behavior to me, the section is protected so it cannot be modified, this extends to updating fields as well. You might have some luck if you embed a MacroButton field into your document in an unprotected range that will update fields when double clicked by the user.